# How to create a relative path to video in Middleman / Padrino?

Tags: ruby, padrino, middleman

I am using `set :relative_links, true` for my Middleman project. This works for `image_tag` and `link_to`, but how can I create a relative link to a static asset like a video in a `/videos` directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this I think this is what you need

https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/245